# mysql ignore \" on json insertion

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

i have to store html content in the database as json along other data. when i get the certain html data in javascript, i wrap it to a object alongside other data and convert it to json string which apply escape " which avoid any conflicts. when i pass the data by AJAX to php and insert it to MYSQL , in the database table there is no escape " and so when i read data and try to deserialize , it makes an error because of invalid json (on both php and js)/

when i convert to json by js i have something like

```
{"cat":"education-content","id":"45a93325-2bab-4296-cc8d-92e7994dabe0","contents":"<p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(224, 62, 45);\" data-mce-style=\"background-color: #e03e2d;\">شستنیتشنسذیت سشای تشس ایتنشسا تینشاسنتیاستشن ایتنشس ایتنش</span></p><p><span style=\"color: rgb(22, 145, 121);\" data-mce-style=\"color: #169179;\">شتسنیاتشسایتنشساتینشساتیناشس یاشست نیاتنشس </span></p><p><span style=\"font-size: 14pt;\" data-mce-style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><strong>سشیتاشتنسیاش</strong></span></p><p><br data-mce-bogus=\"1\"></p>"}
```

but in database table it is stored as

```
{"cat":"education-content","id":"45a93325-2bab-4296-cc8d-92e7994dabe0","contents":"<p><span style="background-color: rgb(224, 62, 45);" data-mce-style="background-color: #e03e2d;">شستنیتشنسذیت سشای تشس ایتنشسا تینشاسنتیاستشن ایتنشس ایتنش</span></p><p><span style="color: rgb(22, 145, 121);" data-mce-style="color: #169179;">شتسنیاتشسایتنشساتینشساتیناشس یاشست نیاتنشس </span></p><p><span style="font-size: 14pt;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>سشیتاشتنسیاش</strong></span></p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>"}
```

this json is generated by jquery as

```
 var education_obj={
            cat : cat,
            id : id,
            contents : contents

        };


        var item_wrapp_json = JSON.stringify(education_obj);
```

which is passed by ajax. i checked the json in last moment of insertion in php which is okay.

EDIT: php code that insert items.

```
$citems_query = "INSERT INTO `course_items_tbl`(`CIID`, `CSFK`, `CFK`, `CIORDER`, `CIOPTIONS`) VALUES ";

       

        foreach($data_obj["courseSections"] as $item){


            $sectionID = $item["section_id"];
            $sectionName = $item["section_name"];
            $sectionType = $item["section_type"];



            //$item["section_questions"] this is the json string from js
            foreach($item["section_questions"] as $qitem){

                

                $test = $qitem;

                
                

                
                $citems_query .= "('".$qid."','".$sectionID."','".$course_id."', ". $qorder ." , '".$qitem."' ),";
                
                $qorder++;
            }
```

Comment: Show the PHP code interacting with the database. Do you use parameterized queries? You probably don't and that's problematic in several ways. It may also explain your current problem, as \ is an escape character in MySQL too.

Comment: i edited my question ... and also remove some code which are nonsense to this manner to avoid confusion. i generate query followed by iteration on each item to be insert to get the query with multiple values sets

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought, you use string concatenation to get values into the query. That's not good as it may produce funny results (like the problem you have) and makes the program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Rewrite it to use parameterized queries.

Comment: In MySQL a shash symbol is default quoting symbol. If you want to use it as regular then you must either quote (i.e. double) it or define another quoting symbol (ESCAPE character) in a statement (if the statement supports).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `addslashes()` to escape the quotes before inserting it to the database. On fetching you can use `stripslashes()` the retrieve the original string.

Comment: this also works to add addslashes() before insertion however @sticky bit solution is more elegant